# How to combine two different type of lists in haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, combinations

How can I combine two different types of lists and traverse the result in Haskell?

For example:

```
input: [1,2,3]  ['A','B','C'],
output: ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"].
```

I tried making an example using `Int` and `Char`, like:

```
combine :: Int -> Char -> String
combine a b = show b ++ show a
```

This doesn't work, however, because if I use this function for `combine 3 'A'`, the output will be `"'A'3"`, not `"A3"`.

Answer (score 3):

`show :: Char -> String` will indeed put single quotes around the character:

```
*Main> show 'A'
"'A'"
```

But since a `type String = [Char]`, we can use:

```
combine :: Int -> Char -> String
combine i c = c : show i
```

So here we construct a list of characters with `c` as the head (the first character), and `show i` (the representation of the integer) as tail.

Now we can use list comprehension to make a combination of two lists:

```
combine_list :: [Int] -> [Char] -> [String]
combine_list is cs = [combine i c | c <- cs, i <- is]
```

This then generates the output:

```
*Main> combine_list [1,2,3]  ['A','B','C']
["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do as follows;

```
combiner :: [Char] -> [Int] -> [String]
combiner cs xs = (:) <$> cs <*> (show <$> xs)

*Main> combiner ['A','B','C'] [1,2,3]
["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]
```

Here `(:) <$> cs` (where `<$>` is infix `fmap`) will construct an applicative list functor while `show <$> xs` is like `map show xs` yielding `["1","2","3"]` and by `<*>` we just apply the applicative list to `["1","2","3"]` resulting `["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]`